# O que são MIME types?

Tags: javascript, html, mime-type

O que são MIME types ?

E qual é a sua importância para  renderização das páginas/arquivos corretamente?

O seu uso é obrigatório ou depende do navegador ?

Se não declarados, os navegadores podem assumir um comportamento diferente na hora do tratamento?

## Exemplo:

```
<script type='text/javascript'></script>
```

mas também funciona assim:

```
<script></script>
```

Comment: [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3828381/4258986) tem uma explicação bem objetiva e eficaz sobre o assunto (está em inglês).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions. É um padrão usado para indicar como o conteúdo existente em uma mensagem de e-mail deve ser tratado, tais como:

- codificação usada,
- formato do dado,
- separação em partes
- e outras informações específicas.

Sem essa informação o software que vai interpretá-lo não sabe como tratar de forma adequada (até poderia fazer uma análise do conteúdo, mas nem todos casos isso seria possível e seria bem mais complicado). Em geral isto roteará o conteúdo para uma parte específica do software (um *engine* renderizador, um interpretador de linguagem, um *plugin*, uma ação especifica que o cliente sabe manipular, ou um software externo, etc.).

Hoje o MIME é usado para outros protocolos além dos utilizados para e-mail.

O MIME pode conter várias informações a mais conhecida é o [*content type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

O que foi usado no exemplo é um *content type*. Ele deixa claro para o navegador que aquilo é um *script* escrito na linguagem JavaScript e deve chamar seu interpretador e delegar o que fazer com aquilo.

A primeira parte indica que o conteúdo é um texto puro. Poderia ser outro tipo de mídia ou aplicação (a ser chamada), por exemplo. A segunda parte é mais específica indicando como ele deve ser interpretado.

Outras informações comumente usadas são a versão do MIME, metadados e forma como o conteúdo está inserido (*Content Disposition*) e codificação (*Content-Transfer-Encoding*).

[Artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).

[Lista de MIMEs "reconhecidos" pela IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Alguns navegadores conseguem decidir sozinhos o que fazer com alguns conteúdos, como é o caso de *script* JavaScript. Mas o padrão exige que ele seja usado. E sim, se está fora do padrão, o navegador **pode** assumir um comportamento inesperado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 Resposta completa,obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

MIME significa Multi-purpose Internet Mail Extensions. Tipos MIME formam um  padrão de classificação de tipos de arquivos na Internet. Programas de Internet, como servidores Web e navegadores todos têm uma lista de tipos MIME, para que eles possam transferir arquivos do mesmo tipo, da mesma forma, não importa qual sistema operacional eles estão trabalhando.

Um tipo MIME tem duas partes: um tipo e um subtipo. Eles são separados por uma barra. Por exemplo, o tipo de MIME para arquivos do Microsoft Word é application e o subtipo é msword. Juntos, o tipo MIME completo é application / msword.

Fonte: http://www.aibn.com/help/Learn/mimetypes.html